# MariaDBConnector/Python Connection Pools get slower to get connections with each connection in the pool

Tags: python, mariadb, fastapi

I'm using the MariaDB/Python connector on Python 3.11, Linux Mint, latest version of MariaDB, etc and I can't for the life of me figure this out. I have a simple function called `get_connection()` that returns a `Connection` from `mariadb.ConnectionPool`, and with `pool_size=1`, the response time in Postman is 75ms, but with `pool_size=5`, the response time is 400ms. There is nothing else going on in this request except for a FastAPI Middleware that opens and closes this connection. There comes a threshold with this issue where it's simply faster to open a new connection per request, as opposed to using a `ConnectionPool`.

I expect `get_connection()` to have the same response time whether I have `pool_size=5` or `pool_size=64`.

Here is the code:

```py
POOL = mariadb.ConnectionPool(
    host=os.environ.get("DATABASE_IP"),
    port=3306,
    user=os.environ.get("DATABASE_USER"),
    password=os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
    pool_name="poolname",
    pool_size=5,
    pool_reset_connection=True
)


def get_connection() -> Connection:
    """
    Returns a DatabaseHandler object
    :return:
    """
    before = datetime.datetime.now()
    connection = POOL.get_connection()
    after = datetime.datetime.now()
    print((after - before).microseconds)
    return connection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We experienced the same problem when running [internal benchmarks](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python/tree/1.1/testing/benchmarks) with connection pool instead of a single connection.

The problem is caused by unnecessary health check (sending MYSQL_PING) when iterating over unused connections.

Fix is planned for 1.1.6 (scheduled for mid Feb)

For tracking status of this issue, please check [CONPY-245](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-245)

Update (Feb 1): Issue has been fixed and will be available in 1.1.6 release:

```
$ python3.11 conpy245.py
Acquiring 100000 connections via Pool
Pool size: 64
Average time per connection: 19 ms

Acquiring 100000 connections without Pool
Average time per connection: 170 ms
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll add make sure to update when it comes out!